# Is it possible to develop an iphone app that tracks use of other apps

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to develop an iphone app that tracks use of other apps. Basically is it possible to track how long a person used each iphone app on their phone?

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you wrote the other apps it is. Basically it would be an interface to something like http://www.flurry.com/. Otherwise no.